# EF 5 SQL logging

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, entity-framework-5

I am following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499902/Profiling-Entity-Framework-in-code) to get the query generated by EF and storing them in a database table. The generated query looks like this:

```
declare :p0 decimal 

set :p0 = '277'

delete "schema_name"."table_name"

where ("column_name" = :p0)
```

which is not executable in oracle, I need the query to be executable so that any person who have 0 knowledge of SQL; can copy paste the generated query and use them. Can it be done? Or any sort of workaround for this will help. Point to be noted that I'm using EF 5.0. Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like valid SQL to me. Which part of it cannot be executed?

Comment: @ParthShah :P0 part, it throws error: <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete and exists prior